# Is there a concurrent rate limit to MSFT graph (Outlook mail)?

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

currently I am making a small app that will provide users with the ability to mark multiple email messages as being "read" in one click.

Unfortunately, the MSFT graph API does not support multiple update calls as specified [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_update)

So what I am doing right now is using asynchronous IO server side to send multiple REST API requests simultaneously.

I know there is a 60 requests/min limit. But is there a simultaneous connection limit as well?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Yogesh I am not getting any errors so far. Im just asking so I wont have to run into them in the future

Comment: I guess you mark emails as read, doing the REST request yourself, right? Because I try to use the `Microsoft.Graph` nuget package to do the same thing and things don't go so well...: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394264/microsoftgraph-api-fails-to-mark-a-message-as-read

Comment: @NoOne I have since given up on MSFT and now only support gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simulatenous connection limit because access to store is serialized. I would recommend going with 4 simultaneous requests at max (Maybe even lower). From Exchange Store perspective all access to store is serialized irrespective of the App.

Microsoft Graph also plans to support batching soon so when they do enable it you can make one call and update read flag for multiple messages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How soon is soon? Ill be honest, trying to interface with MSFT graph for the last couple of months has been an incredibly bad nightmare when I compare it to interfacing with google. The docs are lacking, and sometimes deviate from actual results (e.g. returning 501 instead of 404 depending on MSFT account type) and the whole entire API system is so bogged down by these random restraints (This limit + the newly introduced 60 reqs/min limit) that the whole thing feels more like a gimmick for students to play with vs something you can build an app/solution on top of

Comment: Also, when you say that all requests are serialized. What exactly do you mean? Do you mean all requests are processed 1 at a time?

Also is this restriction per app? or per app/per user?

Comment: This is per app/user.

Comment: Is this per app/actual user or per app/user access token?

Comment: It's for accessing user when we have an accessing user or target mailbox when there isn't a accessing user (app only)